# MX Record lookup and check

Tags: python, mx-record

I need to create a tool that will check a domains live mx records against what should be expected (we have had issues with some of our staff fiddling with them and causing all incoming mail to redirected into the void)

Now I won't lie, I'm not a competent programmer in the slightest! I'm about 40 pages into "dive into python" and can read and understand the most basic code. But I'm willing to learn rather than just being given an answer.

So would anyone be able to suggest which language I should be using?

I was thinking of using python and starting with something along the lines of using 0s.system() to do a (dig +nocmd domain.com mx +noall +answer) to pull up the records, I then get a bit confused about how to compare this to a existing set of records.

Sorry if that all sounds like nonsense!

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With [dnspython](https://www.dnspython.org/) module (not built-in, you must `pip install` it):

```
>>> import dns.resolver
>>> domain = 'hotmail.com'
>>> for x in dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX'):
...     print(x.to_text())
...
5 mx3.hotmail.com.
5 mx4.hotmail.com.
5 mx1.hotmail.com.
5 mx2.hotmail.com.
```

Comment: You should mention, that one needs the `dnspython` module for that.

Comment: For python 3 use `dnspython3`

Comment: @TusharSadhwani's comment is now out of date - according to the `dnspython3` page on PyPI: *"dnspython3 has been superseded by the regular dnspython kit, which now supports both Python 2 and Python 3."*

Comment: I had to use `query` instead of `resolve`: `for x in dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX'):` ...

Comment: And now @Artemis' comment has been superseded. "Python 2.x support ended with 1.16.0. Dnspython 2.2.1 requires Python 3.6 or later."

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/), a module that should do the lookups for you just fine without needing to resort to system calls.

Comment: I haven't tried it.  "2.4 or later" generally doesn't mean what it sounds like, but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: Now, it's compatible with python3, from pip it's *dnspython3* package

Answer (score 1):

the above solutions are correct. some things I would like to add and update.

- the `dnspython` has been updated to be used with python3 and it has superseeded the `dnspython3` library so use of `dnspython` is recommended
- the **domain** will strictly take in the **domain** and nothing else.

for example: **dnspython.org** is valid domain, not **[www.dnspython.org](http://www.dnspython.org)**

here's a function if you want to get the mail servers for a domain.

```py
def get_mx_server(domain: str = "dnspython.org") -> str:
    mail_servers = resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX')
    mail_servers = list(set([data.exchange.to_text()
                             for data in mail_servers]))
    return ",".join(mail_servers)
```